# Scalability of z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I would like to improve the scalability of SMT solving. I have actually implemented the incremental solving. But I would like to improve more. Any other general methods to improve it without the knowledge of the problem itself?

Answer (score 10):

There's no single "trick" that can make z3 scale better for an arbitrary problem. It really depends on what the actual problem is and what sort of constraints you have. Of course, this goes for any general computing problem, but it really applies in the context of an SMT solver.

Having said that, here're some general ideas based on my experience, roughly in the order of ease of use:

**Read the `Programming Z3` book** This is a very nice write-up and will teach you a ton of things about how z3 is architected and what the best idioms are. You might hit something in there that directly applies to your problem: https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html

**Keep booleans as booleans not integers** Never use integers to represent booleans. (That is, use `1` for true, `0` for false; multiplication for `and` etc. This is a terrible idea that kills the powerful SAT engine underneath.) Explicitly convert if necessary. Most problems where people tend to deploy such tricks involve counting how many booleans are true etc.: Such problems should be solved using the pseudo-boolean tactics that's built into the solver. (Look up `pbEq`, `pbLt` etc.)

**Don't optimize unless absolutely necessary** The optimization engine is not incremental, nor it is well optimized (pun intended). It works rather slowly compared to all other engines, and for good reason: Optimization modulo theories is a very tricky thing to do. Avoid it unless you really have an optimization problem to tackle. You might also try to optimize "outside" the solver: Make a `SAT` call, get the results, and making subsequent calls asking for "smaller" cost values. You may not hit the optimum using this trick, but the values might be good enough after a couple of iterations. Of course, how well the results will be depends entirely on your problem.

**Case split** Try reducing your constraints by case-splitting on key variables. Example: If you're dealing with floating-point constraints, say; do a case split on normal, denormal, infinity, and NaN values separately. Depending on your particular domain, you might have such semantic categories where underlying algorithms take different paths, and mixing-and-matching them will always give the solver a hard time. Case splitting based on context can speed things up.

**Use a faster machine and more memory** This goes without saying; but having plenty of memory can really speed up certain problems, especially if you have a lot of variables. Get the biggest machine you can!

**Make use of your cores** You probably have a machine with many cores, further your operating system most likely provides fine-grained multi-tasking. Make use of this: Start many instances of z3 working on the same problem but with different tactics, random seeds, etc.; and take the result of the first one that completes. Random seeds can play a significant role if you have a huge constraint set, so running more instances with different seed values can get you "lucky" on average.

**Try to use parallel solving** Most SAT/SMT solver algorithms are sequential in nature. There has been a number of papers on how to parallelize some of the algorithms, but most engines do not have parallel counterparts. z3 has an interface for parallel solving, though it's less advertised and rather finicky. Give it a try and see if it helps out. Details are here: https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-parallel-z3

**Profile** Profile z3 source code itself as it runs on your problem, and see
where the hot-spots are. See if you can recommend code improvements to developers to address these. (Better yet, submit a pull request!) Needless to say, this will require a deep study of z3 itself, probably not suitable for end-users.

***Bottom line:*** There's no free lunch. No single method will make z3 run better for your problems. But above ideas might help improve run times. If you describe the particular problem you're working on in some detail, you'll most likely get better advice as it applies to your constraints.